# Does Docker Compose Conflict with Turborepo Pipelines?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, continuous-integration, monorepo, turborepo

I have a turbo monorepo that I want to perform end-to-end tests on in a CI environment. All of my applications are containerized and some external services are hosted by container during development via docker compose.

I was having trouble working out how docker was supposed to fit into turborepo during development, and I realized they accomplish a lot of the same things:

Compose allows services to define their dependents, and so long as tests are run during the build phase, the results can be cached. Multi-stage builds and service profiles / multiple compose files can be configured to represent more complicated and interdependent tasks.

This seems to able to accomplish the same thing as turborepo pipelines, with the bonus that everything is containerized during development. However, turbo pipelines are in my opinion much more user friendly for this use case, although they cannot orchestrate several containerized applications.

So my question is does the pipeline feature of turborepo conflict with docker for development? If I want to containerize my applications during development should I forgo using pipelines completely? Or is there a more preferable setup, for example each containerized application has “up” and “down” scripts for starting their containers that turbo leverages?